# Добавить стандартный параметр ко всем ответам

Tags: php, laravel, controller, response

Есть ли возможность добавить стандартный параметр ко всем ответам в laravel? 
К примеру что бы

```
return response([
    'status' => 'ok'
], 200);
```

возвращал не только status, но и какое-нибудь дефолтное значение (к примеру версию).

```
{
   "version": "0.1",
   "status": "ok"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение при помощи After Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->header('version', '0.1');

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return response($content)
            ->header('Version', '0.1');
```

Comment: поясните ответ, непонятно

Comment: В этом варианте придется добавлять ->header() ко всем существующим response().

Comment: можно так if(true){return response($content) ->header('Version', '0.1');}else{return response($content);}